# Setting Symbols in Form View - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problems trying to set symbol values in a form view.  My view has a couple instance variables being used, @task and @team, @team is the one im having issues with.  Tasks have a :team value that needs to be set.  In this view @team holds a value, but when I hit the "Create" button and make a post, the @team value is lost, and @task contains no team value.

Here is the view I'm dealing with:

Note: the ":team => @task.team" line doesn't work

```
<% form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <% @task.team = Team.find(@team) %>
  <p><%= @task.team.title%></p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :hours %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :hours %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :team %><br />
    <% :team => @task.team %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create'%>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The Post method that gets called on Create:

```
 def create
    @task = Task.new(params[:task])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@task, :notice => 'Task was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @task, :status => :created, :location => @task }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @task.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Should teams be a select box that you can choose the team from? Your team symbol will not live past this page. I think you'll need to use a form element to hold the team value for it to reach the form post.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that. I have an "add task" for each team, the @team instance variable holds the team that called the new task view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jordinl is right when he mentions that you could use a hidden form field. You can also automatically scope the task to the team in the controller by doing something like

```
@team = Team.find(params[:team])
```

and then

```
@team.tasks << Task.new(params[:task])
```

You'll need to have a has_many association set up in the team model for tasks

```
has_many :tasks
```

for this to work. Each task will also need the team id as well but it sounds like you already have that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set it as a hidden field?

```
<%= f.hidden_field :team, :value => @task.team %>
```